# See products within the order?

Tags: magento-1.8, orders

How can I get all the products within the orders of a determine time interval, lets say from January to March ?

Comment: have a look into the reports

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: In the backend under Reports you can see a lot of reports, just check them out, I think some of them show order items

Comment: But I need them in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested the code, but it should work. And also, change the dates to whatever you like

```
$from = date('YYYY-MM-DD');
$to = date('YYYY-MM-DD');

Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
        'from' => $from,
        'to' => $to,
        'date' => true,
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see this in admin-end under

```
Reports -> Products -> Products Ordered
```